# How can I prove the following? compact operator on a dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let X be Banach space, $ x_{0}\in X $ and  $\phi_{0}\in X^{*}$. Define$ T:X^{*}\to X^{*} $ bt $ T(\psi) =\psi (x_{0})\phi_{0}$ for $ \psi\in X^{*} $
then T is compact in $ X^{*} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of $T$ is one-dimensional, it is contained in $span(\phi_0)$. So $T$ is compact.